# Windows Phone 8.1 MVVMCROSS ViewModel is null

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

What could be the reason that the `Viewmodel` Property of the FirstView is NULL after startup?

In `MVVMCROSS` after the setup an instance of the `ViewModel` is made and it searches for his View.

In my case that works all fine, but the property `Viewmodel` or `DataContext` is NULL. I can make a new instance but there should be already one around.

Comment: Perhaps editing your question to include a simple view where this occurs might help. Eg does it occur in a tip calc tutorial app - if so, where in that app?

Comment: Sry Stuart, it was just a temporary failure. I don't know where it came from. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I don't know why but today it is working. Strange, I didn't change the code at all.

Comment: This happens to me quite often, but I have no clue on how to make it work again.. Seems like a MVVMCross Bug!